# Macro to close all open Modules

Tags: vba, module

Prior to 2017 I had a VBA macro routine that would close all open VBA modules (except the one containing the macro).

It looked SOMETHING like this:

```
Sub Close_Modules_1() 
    Dim iTemp As Integer
 
    For iTemp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.Windows.Count To 1 Step -1
        With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE
            .Windows (iTemp)                             '<- Invalid use of property
        End With
    Next
    Debug.Print "Done."
End Sub
```

1. Can anyone provide a working routine that closes all VBA modules?  I've ended up with over 100 open modules at times.
2. Did Microsoft in its wisdom make acting on modules illegal in Excel 2016/2019/Excel 365?

Thanks in advance for helpful ideas.

Comment: Use `.Windows(iTemp).Close `.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Private Sub X_Click()
    Dim iTemp As Integer
    For iTemp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.Windows.Count To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.Windows(iTemp).Caption
        If InStr(ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.Windows(iTemp).Caption, "(") > 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.Windows(iTemp).Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Do not forget to check this option first:

[image: Option]

Comment: Thank you so much Toni!  Works great.  Bonus points to you!  This is a great example of everything that Stackoverflow can me.